# Convertir número arábico a romano con Python

Tags: python, constructor, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que convertir números arábicos a romanos dentro de una clase a la que le paso un número y recibe dos atributos. El primero de ellos un número normal mientras que el segundo es el número en romano.

Por ahora he hecho esto:

```
    
    def __init__(self, normal):
        self.normal = normal;
        self.romano = self.convert_to_roman(normal)
   
    def convert_to_roman(self, normal):
        #if self.normal == 1672: 
         #   valor = "MDCLXXII"
        #else:
         #   valor = "Hi"
            
        num = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 
           100, 400, 500, 900, 1000]
        sym = ["I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", 
           "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"]
        i = 12
        valor = normal
        while valor:
            div = valor // num[i]
            valor %= num[i]
 
            while div:
                print(sym[i], end = "")
                div -= 1
            i -= 1

        return valor
    
minumero = Numero(1672)
minumero.normal
minumero.convert_to_roman(minumero)
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-b6e15fc0c1ce> in <module>
     30 minumero = Numero(1672)
     31 minumero.normal
---> 32 minumero.convert_to_roman(minumero)

<ipython-input-45-b6e15fc0c1ce> in convert_to_roman(self, normal)
     18         valor = normal
     19         while valor:
---> 20             div = valor // num[i]
     21             valor %= num[i]
     22 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'Numero' and 'int'
```

¿Alguien sabría como hacer esto correctamente?

Comment: Y cómo está definido `Numero`?

Comment: class Numero():

Comment: La implementación es un pequeño laberinto. Si quieres puedo explicar con más detalle cómo mejorarla. Pero de mano la llamada que haces al final debería ser `minumero.convert_to_roman(minumero.normal)` ya que lo que espera ese método es un entero y no un `Numero`. Por otro lado, esa función no retorna el resultado en números romanos, sino que retorna 0 (el valor final de `valor`). El romano simplemente lo imprime, por lo que no tiene mucho sentido que la llames desde el constructor y asignes el resultado a `self.romano`

Comment: Unas anotaciones adicionales: los romanos no conocían el cero; de modo que debes validar que sea mayor que cero, y con esa notación sólo puedes representar valores menores que 4000, en la edad media idearon un modelo de barras superiores para multiplicar por 1000. (No creo que aquí funcione).

Comment: @abulafia si puedes indicarme como lo harías tu te lo agradecería enormemente!

Answer (score 1):

El error que tiene el código es que le estás pasando como parámetro a `convert_to_roman()` la variable `minumero`, la cual es de tipo `Numero`, pero ese método parece esperar un entero ya que lo usa para operar con él. Por tanto lo que deberías pasarle es `minumero.normal`, que sí que es un entero.

En cualquier caso el diseño del programa no es del todo correcto. El código es un poco más enrevesado de lo que debería. En concreto veo un par de cosas mal:

- El método `convert_to_roman()` no necesista recibir como parámetro el número a convertir, ya que ese número lo puede sacar del propio objeto (estaría en `self.numero`). Si obligas a pasar un número como parámetro no habría ninguna razón para usar OOP, y `convert_to_roman()` podría ser una función "normal" en vez de un método.
- El método `convert_to_roman()` va imprimiendo por pantalla el número romano. En general los métodos y funciones no deberían imprimir cosas por pantalla, sino retornar lo que se espera de ellas (en este caso se espera una cadena que sea la traducción a número romano). Ya el programa que invoque ese método se ocupará de imprimir el resultado, si es que quiere imprimirlo, o de almacenarlo en otra parte, si es que quiere almacenarlo.
- Tal como tienes `convert_to_roman()` retorna `valor`, pero esta variable será cero cuando se salga del bucle. Así que en vez de estar retornando la cadena convertida en romanos, estás retornando cero. Por tanto en el constructor estás asignando cero a `self.romano`, y no tiene pinta de que quisieras hacer eso.
- El constructor llama a `self.convert_to_roman()`, pero luego, desde el programa principal, llamas otra vez a `minumero.convert_to_roman()`. Si ya has hecho la conversión una vez no tiene sentido volver a hacerla. Hay que decidir si prefieres hacer la conversión desde el constructor o desde fuera. Digamos que la hacemos desde el constructor. En ese caso `self.romano` ya tendrá el resultado de esa conversión, por lo que desde fuera bastará con imprimir `minumero.romano`.

Si además añadimos el detalle señalado por **quevedo**, podemos verificar en el constructor que el número pasado está en los límites permitidos. Si no lo está elevaremos una excepción (esto quizás sea material aún desconocido para tí, pero no es muy complejo como vas a ver).

El código por tanto con todas estas consideraciones quedará así:

```
class Numero:    
    def __init__(self, normal):
      if normal<1 or normal>4000:
        raise ValueError("No se soportan números menores de 1 o mayores de 4000")
      self.normal = normal;
      self.romano = self.convert_to_roman()
   
    def convert_to_roman(self):
        num = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 
           100, 400, 500, 900, 1000]
        sym = ["I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", 
           "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"]
        romano = []
        i = 12
        valor = self.normal
        while valor:
            div = valor // num[i]
            valor %= num[i]
            while div:
                romano.append(sym[i])
                div -= 1
            i -= 1

        return "".join(romano)
    
minumero = Numero(1672)
print(minumero.normal)
print(minumero.romano)
```

Fíjate cómo en el programa principal basta con instanciar `Numero(1672)` y ya tendremos en `minumero.romano` el resultado de la conversión.

Para esa conversión, en lugar de ir imprimendo las cifras romanas, las voy guardando en una lista y al final retorno la cadena que resulta de concatenar los elementos de esa lista (el `"".join()`).

Si intentas `Numero(0)` por ejemplo, verás cómo se genera una excepción.

Comment: Genial! ha sido de gran ayuda,